# Is there a JDBC driver which wraps a WSO2 Data Service?

Tags: jdbc, wso2

I use OGSA-DAI as a middleware for data integration. The problem is that OGSA-DAI works with RDF, XML, Relational and Flat File Data Resources. However, in one case data are provided through a "local" middleware, i.e. as WSO2 Data Services.

My question is whether there is an implementation of a JDBC driver as a wrapper of a WSO2 Data Service.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing as a JDBC driver wrapping a data service. Basically a data service is a typical SOAP web service, or a REST service. And for SOAP web services, you will get a WSDL, which can be used to code generate stubs, and these stubs can be used to call the target data service. So it will not make sense to map these web service operations into a JDBC driver.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: Adding: And mapping the JDBC contract like transactions, data type conversion, BLOBs, PreparedStatement, ... ontop of a protocol which does not provide theese abstractions is just futile.

Comment: However in the case of OGSA-DAI integration middleware which also provides data services a JDBC driver had been developed for previous versions (http://ogsadai-jdbc.sourceforge.net/)